# Darken a .Net Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, modal-dialog, touchscreen

I have a 1080p touchscreen application. When a modal pops up, i want to emphasize that by darkening the main form.

Right now i use a second form, the size of the main form, that is black and has 50% opacity. Whenever a modal needs to appear, i open the opaque form, and then open the desired modal.

I feel this is a bit devious for my purpose. Its also not asshole-proof that when the user alt tabs, the forms will glitch out of sequence.

Is there a better way to achieve the darkening effect. Perhaps by darkening the main form from within itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some code, very similar to the method in Thomas's answer. Note to use the `Darkness` property in a `Try...Finally` block, to make sure you never leave the form in the dark state.

```
Public Class Form1


Private _PB As PictureBox

Public WriteOnly Property Darkness
    Set(value)
        If value Then
            Dim Bmp = New Bitmap(Bounds.Size.Width, Bounds.Size.Height)
            Me.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, Bounds.Size))
            Using g = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
                Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(125, Color.Black))
                g.FillRectangle(Brush, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, Bmp.Size))
            End Using
            _PB = New PictureBox
            Me.Controls.Add(_PB)
            _PB.Size = Bounds.Size
            _PB.Location = Bounds.Location - PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
            _PB.Image = Bmp
            _PB.BringToFront()
        Else
            If _PB IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(_PB)
                _PB.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub btnDialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDialog.Click
    Try
        Darkness = True

        MsgBox("Modal dialog")

    Finally
        Darkness = False
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tested rendering a PictureBox over tabs? It's been my experience that they resist all attempts to render things above them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by doing the following:

- Place a hidden picturebox with dock:fill on the main form,
- Take a screenshot of the current screen and darken it
- assign the image to the picturebox and make it visible
- open the modal in a new win

when the modal is dismissed

- hide the picturebox

Answer (score 0):

It really stupid that VB.net doesn't have this function built into it. Here's what you do to get around it:

*Make a new form and call it **Shade***. I'm going to *assume your main form is called **frmMain***. For the sake of clarity, *lets assume the form you're launching is called **dlgX***.

Add the following lines in the Load event of dlgX (that's the sub with dlgX.Load or Me.Load or MyBase.Load):

```
    Shade.Opacity = 0.001
    Shade.Show()
    Shade.Location = frmMain.Location ' Form location will only update if the form is visible.
    Shade.Hide()
    Shade.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None 'This gets rid of the windows Titlebar and window border.
    Shade.Size = frmMain.Size 
    Shade.BackColor = Color.Black
    Shade.Opacity = 0.5
    Shade.Show() ' Form size will only update the next time you show it.
    Shade.TopMost = True ' Puts Shade over main form
    Me.TopMost = True ' Puts current form over shade
```

Under all events that dismiss the form dlgX (OK.click, Cancel.click, etc), add the following lines:

```
Shade.Close
```

Or you can even make your own sub that handles all events where the form is closed:

```
Private Sub DispelShades(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Shade.Close()
End Sub
```

This is way simpler than the PictureBox scenario and you don't have to mess with layering issues and having to ensure that the PictureBox renders on  top of everything (for example, tabs really do not like having things rendered above them and they will not let you render a picture box above them). Rendering a black semi transparent form above your main form gets around all these headaches.

If you have multiple forms to shade, just make a Shad1, Shade2, Shade3 etc.

This is pretty obvious but it's worth stating: if you're shading the main form, you'll also want to make it unclickable by opening dlgX via dlgX.ShowDialog and not dlgX.Show